# Django will delete session record in DB table, if call login without call anthencate first

Tags: django, authentication

In our service, sometime, we need to switch user from one (high privilige) to another without them logging in manually.

After googling, I found a solution, to call `login()` without authentication first, as the following code shows.

```
def handle_change_to_anotheruser(self, request):
    user = User(id=request.GET['uid'])
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
            login(request, user)
            return JsonResponse({'retcode': 0, 'realname': user.teacher.realname})
```

Everything works well, user switching succeed, and new sessionid is created for new user. as the following http response shows
[image]

And wait, weird thing happend, in later HTTP request, DJANGO deleted the session record in DB table "django_session" . And the code of django.contrib.sessions.middleware.py shows if it cannot find session with ID in HTTP request cookie, it will set session-cookie to blank string, thus force user to logout. As following http capture shows

[image]

Why does that happen?

Answer (score 0):

1.Check MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES contains`'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'`.

2.Make sure `'django.contrib.sessions'` is in your INSTALLED_APPS

Then,

```
user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
login(request, user)
if not request.session.session_key:
    request.session.cycle_key()
return JsonResponse({'retcode': 0,'realname':user.teacher.realname})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, expected behaviour. If you look at the source of the [`login()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/contrib/auth/#login) method it does this:

```
if SESSION_KEY in request.session:
    if _get_user_session_key(request) != user.pk or (
            session_auth_hash and
            request.session.get(HASH_SESSION_KEY) != session_auth_hash):
        # To avoid reusing another user's session, create a new, empty
        # session if the existing session corresponds to a different
        # authenticated user.
        request.session.flush()
```

i.e., it flushes the session if the `user` stored in the session has changed - which is exactly what you are doing.

This is a necessary security measure - otherwise it would be possible to inject one user's session into another's!

My suggestion in your case would be to either find a better way to do this (changing a user mid session while retaining all other data seems pretty risky). Alternatively grab the session data you want to retain before logging the user in, log them in, and then restore it. Something like this:

```
temp_session['somedata'] = request.session.get('somedata')
# So on for whatever else you want to retain
login(request, user)
# Repopulate session
for k in temp_session:
    request.session[k] = temp_session[k]
```

Comment: Login method only flush the data in original session. That's not my issue. What I met is Django create new session for the user it changed to, but soon in handling of later http request, it delete new session record in the database.